# Does the inspect function in Chrome have a item to search a dom element by its id?

Tags: html, google-chrome, inspect

Does the inspect function in Chrome have a item to search a dom element by its id?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried control-F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! All you need to do is press `CTRL+F` (`CMD+F` for Mac) on your keyboard while in Inspect Element, and you can search for the ID name.